# Why can't React add the keys itself?

Tags: reactjs

I do understand that React requires those keys to identify repeating elements, but why should we even care? As far as I got so far, we as developers do not seem to use them for anything. It's only for React. Can't it add the keys itself, wherever and whenever it needs them?

Comment: The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) explain this. You might also want to read up on [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html). It might be that they're not needed in your usecase (in which case you can ignore the error message) but there are plenty of usecases where they are.

Comment: Dear @jayarjo, I don't understand what exactly is the question here. You clearly know why React needs keys, are you asking why the developers of React don't make it an implicit feature? Shouldn't you ask them directly?

Comment: I thought maybe they will respond here if I tag it appropriately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so that you can do things like re-order elements.

> where the identity and state of each child must be maintained across render passes, you can uniquely identify each child by assigning it a `key`
>
> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with `key` will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

I don't know that there'd be a way to automatically generate a key that would work for that, and in any case there isn't such automatic generation in React.